# Powershell Iterate Through Two Directories and Write Contents to CSV

Tags: windows, powershell

I have to write the contents of two directories to a CSV where Directory 1 is Column 1 and Directory 2 is Column 2.

I am fairly new to Powershell so please be gentle.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$source_loc = "Z:\Dir1"
$dest_loc = "Y:\Dir2"
$outfile = "C:\Outfile.csv"

$source = get-ChildItem $source_loc
$dest = get-ChildItem $dest_loc

Remove-Item $outfile -ErrorAction Ignore
Add-Content $outfile "Old URL, New URL"

$max = ( $source | Measure-Object ).Count

For ( $i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++ )
{
    $cur = $source | Select-Object -Index $i | Select Name
    $old = "http://thisisawebsite.web/oldurl/" + $cur

    $cur = $dest | Select-Object -Index $i | Select Name
    $new = "http://thisisawebsite.web/newurl/" + $cur
    $line = $old + ',' + $new
    Add-Content $outfile $line
}
```

The problem I am having is that right now the output of Outfile.csv looks like this:

```
http://thisisawebsite.web/oldurl/@{Name=File1.ext},http://thisisawebsite.web/newurl/@{Name=File1.ext}
http://thisisawebsite.web/oldurl/@{Name=File2.ext},http://thisisawebsite.web/newurl/@{Name=File2.ext}
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
http://thisisawebsite.web/oldurl/File1.ext,http://thisisawebsite.web/newurl/File1.ext
http://thisisawebsite.web/oldurl/File2.ext,http://thisisawebsite.web/newurl/File2.ext
```

I tried converting to arrays and indexing into it but it seems to do the same thing.  Do I need to do a substr on the $cur variable and ignore the first 7 characters and then ignore the last one?  I know my code is rubbish so please try your best not to insult me.

Thanks!  ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few simpler ways of doing what you're trying to do, I believe. A quick and dirty way of making this work, however, is expanding  the "name" property that you're selecting. Try this small snippet on the two noted lines :

```
$cur = $source | Select-Object -Index $i | Select -ExpandProperty Name


$cur = $dest | Select-Object -Index $i | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

This should select the Value for the "name" property instead of a hashtable including both.

Another useful thing to note for the future is that with double quotes, you don't need to manually concatenate a variable and a string in powershell.

```
$new = "http://thisisawebsite.web/newurl/" + $cur
```

Is the same as

```
$new = "http://thisisawebsite.web/newurl/$cur"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  That fixed it.  I'm primarily a C programmer so that tends to be how I approach things.  Unfortunately for me, not everything is as wonderful as C!  Thanks again!  ^.^